# What is the error Firebase displaying about?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework

I am having this in my console from time to time by just navigating in my ionic app, I have no idea what it is about.

Any help ?

PS : the firs error regarding the image not found, I get it...

[image]

Comment: 500, something broke on the server (when trying to negotiate a websocket connection), and the warning is about using synchronous XMLHttpRequest - which is bad practice

Comment: First one: use `ng-src` instead of `src` in `<img>` tags